# probability of getting specific consequence

Tags: probability

I roll the dice and puts down the results in his notebook. I want the numbers 3,4,5,2,6,1 to be written in this order. However there can be other numbers in between. How many times on average should I roll the dice in order to get such kind of a result?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have you tried to answer this question yourself? We can help you if you show you’ve at least made an attempt.

Comment: honestly its around 36

Comment: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user46_ejdb1ocYKC_1.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
The length of the sequence = $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5+n_6+6$, where $n_1$ is the number times that the dice has to be rolled before first 3 occurs, $n_2$  is the number times that the dice has to be rolled before first 4 occurs after a 3, and so on. Clearly, $n_i$ are iid and

\begin{equation}
P(n_i = n) = \left(\frac{5} {6}\right)^n\frac{1} {6}. 
\end{equation}

After some algebraic simplifications, we get that the expected value is 42.